# Conditional expression with sh: errors from both [[ $COUNT == 0 ]] and [ $COUNT == 0 ]

Tags: sh

Why is it that the following snipped of code return the following message: **syntax error in conditional expression** and fails.

```
#!/bin/sh
COUNT=`cat annemarie/new_files.txt | wc -l`
if [[ $COUNT -ge 1 ]]; then
  echo "New files found. Stopping deployment"
  exit 0
fi
if [[ $COUNT == 0 ]]; then
  echo "File not found. Continuing deployment"
fi
```

but this passes, but gives me the warning **unary operator expected**, however it doesnt seem as if the code is processed:

```
#!/bin/sh
COUNT=`cat annemarie/new_files.txt | wc -l`
if [ $COUNT -ge 1 ]; then
  echo "New files found. Stopping deployment"
  exit 0
fi
if [ $COUNT == 0 ]; then
  echo "File not found. Continuing deployment"
fi
```

Which is the correct format?

Comment: There are multiple issues. Paste your script on shellcheck.net

Comment: In general -- `/bin/sh` **is not bash**. If you want your scripts to be run with bash, use `#!/bin/bash` (to use an OS-installed version of bash) or `#!/usr/bin/env bash` (to use whichever bash interpreter is first in the PATH -- potentially newer than the OS vendor's one). Questions about scripts that run with `/bin/sh` should be tagged `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Comment: BTW, one thing that's often helpful in figuring out why a script doesn't work the way you expect is running it with commands traced. `sh -x yourscript` will do that -- so f/e, in the prior version of my answer that used `=` instead of `-eq`, you might see it log something like `+ [ \ \ \ 0 = 0 ]`, and would know that the reason the string comparison was unexpectedly coming out false was spaces before the `0` in the output from `wc` making the strings different. (Not all versions of `sh` do escaping like that, so the exact output with nonprintable characters is a little hit-or-miss).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `/bin/sh`, `[[` is not guaranteed to be supported whatsoever -- but `==` inside of `[ ]` is *also* not guaranteed to work. Thus, your code must be:

```
#!/bin/sh
count=$(wc -l <annemarie/new_files.txt)
if [ "$count" -ge 1 ]; then
  echo "New files found. Stopping deployment"
  exit 0
fi
if [ "$count" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "File not found. Continuing deployment"
fi
```

---

Note:

- `[[ ... ]]` is a ksh extension also picked up by bash and zsh. While this has several benefits (among them, preventing string-splitting and glob expansion, and thus making quotes less necessary), it is not specified as part of the POSIX sh standard, and so is not guaranteed to be available at all when a script is run with `/bin/sh`.
- `$(...)` is modern command substitution syntax; it has more predictable behavior when nested or when running commands that contain literal backslashes than does the old, pre-POSIX backtick-based syntax.
- For string comparisons, `==` should be replaced with `=` for portability purposes; see [the POSIX `test` specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), in which `=` is the only string comparison operator. That said, inasmuch as what we want is a *numeric* comparison, `-eq` is arguably the correct operator for the job.
- Expansions must be quoted to prevent string-splitting and globbing.
- `cat foo | bar` is potentially much less efficient than `bar <foo`. (With some commands this is only a minor difference; for commands that can parallelize or seek when given a direct file handle -- such as `sort` or `tail` -- it can be much larger)
- The POSIX standard reserves all-caps names for environment variables and shell builtin names with meaning to the OS and shell themselves, and guarantees that lower-case names will not unexpectedly modify the behavior of POSIX-defined tools. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph.

Comment: As a further optimization, a (valid) POSIX text file with zero lines is also empty, so you could drop the call to `wc` and use `if [ -s annemarie/new_files.txt ]; then echo "File not found"; else exit 0; fi`.